# In a project using WebSocket in Spring and React, event.reason is not appearing in the onclose section

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

```
@Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
        String path = request.getURI().getPath();
        String roomId = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

       
        // 숫자인 경우 연결 거부
        if (isNumeric(roomId)) {
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            String reason = "연결이 거부되었습니다.";
            response.getBody().write(reason.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            response.flush();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is the code on the Spring side.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (client) {
      client.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
        
      };
      client.onmessage = (message) => {
        
      };
      client.onerror = (event) => {
        console.error('WebSocket Error');
      };

      client.onclose = (event) => {
        console.log('WebSocket Connection Closed');
        console.log('Close Code:', event.code);
        console.log('Close Reason:', event.reason);
      };
    }
  }, [client]);
```

This is the code on the React side.

```
 browser.js:28 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/123' failed:
 WebSocket Error
 WebSocket Connection Closed
 Close Code: 1006
 Close Reason:
```

and this is the console log

I want to check certain conditions before establishing a WebSocket connection and, if the connection is denied, I want to send the reason to the client-side. However, even though I followed the instructions given by GPT, the `event.reason` is always empty. What should I do? I would greatly appreciate your help.

tried everything gpt showed